# How do I get rid of these artifacts (matplotlib with LaTeX)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, latex

When running the following minimal example I get strange J-shaped artifacts in the LaTeX-rendered expressions.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc

rc('font',**{'family':'serif','serif':['Times']})
rc('text', usetex=True)
rc(('xtick','ytick','axes'), labelsize=12.0)
rc(('legend'), fontsize=8.0)

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(4,3))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.plot([0,1],[0,1],label=r'$\propto x^1$')
ax1.set_xlabel(r'$x$')
ax1.set_ylabel(r'$\sum_i \chi_i$')

ax1.legend()

fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('minimal.pdf')
```

Output: [image: minimal example]

How can I get rid of them?

Comment: This is probably because there isn't a font on your system similar to `Times` that has the approriate symbols.  What happens if you remove the first `rc` line that sets the font family?  (Your example works perfectly on my system, for what it's worth. I'm guessing that `'serif':['Times']` is getting you Times New Roman, which doesn't have the correct symbols.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joe Kington pointed out in his comment the way to get rid of the artefacts is to use a font that has the correct symbols.

In the minimal example removal of `rc('font',**{'family':'serif','serif':['Times']})` fixes the problem.